# changes not being applied to minified file

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I added this css

```
high {
    background-color: red;
}

medium {
    background-color: yellow;
}

low {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
```

to `wwwroot\css\Site.css`, and when I publish the application with `dotnet publish`, I can see the minified css file is being referenced but it does not contain these new styles.

**bundleconfig.json**

```
// Configure bundling and minification for the project.
// More info at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808241
[
    {
      "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
      // An array of relative input file paths. Globbing patterns supported
      "inputFiles": [
        "wwwroot/css/site.css"
      ]
    },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    // Optionally specify minification options
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    // Optionally generate .map file
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

Why is this happening? How can I ensure that this bundle config is being applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?tabs=netcore-cli%2Caspnetcore2x) useful, where it mentioned the need to add the `BuildBundlerMinifier` package to the project.

So after calling

```
dotnet add package BuildBundlerMinifier
dotnet restore
```

I can see my css updates in the .min.css file